# Null Pointer Exception Groovy

Tags: groovy, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a Null Point Exception, and my Groovy shell is no longer specifying where it is happening.  It *was* saying that there were 3 of them, the first of which occurred at the line `scans.each {item ->`

If you dare...:

```
use( groovy.time.TimeCategory ) {
new File( 'C:\\Users\\pro-services\\Documents\\ScanEngineDetailFake.log' ).eachLine { line ->

  m = line =~ d
  log = line
  matcher = (log =~ /\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}/)

  matcher.count.times {
    a = matcher[it]

    if( a ) {
      if( !prevDate ) {
      prevDate = parseDate( a )
    }
    if (line ==~ c){
      starts ++
      prevDate = parseDate( a )
    }
    if (line ==~ d){
      finishes ++
      def nextDate = parseDate( a )
      deltas << nextDate - prevDate
      scans <<  line
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
def startDate = null
def finDate = null
def filediff = null

76    use( groovy.time.TimeCategory ) {

78  scans.each { item ->

  logs = item
  matcher = (logs =~ /\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}/)

83  matcher.count.times {
    b = matcher[it]

    if (logs ==~ c){
      startDate = parseDate( b )
    }

    if (logs ==~ d){
      finDate = parseDate( b )

 96     filediff = finDate - startDate

      deltas.each { diff ->
        if (diff == filediff){
           n = logs =~ c
           println n[0][1]
           println diff     
        }    
      }   
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?  I've been looking at other nullpointer problems but they all seem specific to the code, so I guess I'll just add this to the library.

Comment: Where is scans defined? I only see you trying to put things in to it, but I don't know what "it" is.

Comment: Oh, scans is a null list defined in the original but above where I started to quote.  I'll fix it on Thursday back at work:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NullPointerException` on line `scans.each`
means that `scans` is a null reference. `scans` has not been initialized correclty. There should be a line like this one: `def scan = []` before, so that `scan` is initialized as an empty list. If you wrote `def scan`, scan is initialized as a null pointer.

Comment: or you could do `scans?.each { item ->` using the null safe operator

Comment: I think at this point in his program scans must not be null. It crashes here because it doesn't enter the condition that fill the list, otherwise it would throw at `scans << line`

Comment: I agree, but the `scans?.each` would show there are no results, so attention would then turn to why the matcher isn't working, and when that then works, attention would turn to why `null << line` is crashing.  I wasn't disagreeing with your answer, I was just pointing out another possible route to take

Comment: Thanks guys.  Still got problems.  Antoine, scans IS defined in my original code as such :`def scans = []`   Tim, using `scans?.each` still throws NPEs, it finds them at lines 76, 78, 83, and 96 (making me think 76 is the root cause) - I've edited my question code to show those line numbers...

Comment: So it actually says that the first NPE is from this line: `use( groovy.time.TimeCategory ) {
`  is this because I've used this method earlier in the code...?